# How can i assign user-list permission to other roles also in laravel for spatie package(ACL Management)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using **Spatie** package for ACL Management in **Laravel** and its working perfectly but i want to ask one question.If i have to assign user-list permission to any role like Manager even it has permission then it generates an error.
and what is the purpose of '**only**' attribute below in constructor and '**permission:role-list**' doesn't assign any function, is there any default behavior?

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission:role-list');
    $this->middleware('permission:role-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
    $this->middleware('permission:role-edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
    $this->middleware('permission:role-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
}
```

should i assume if i have to access any function of role controller than it must have role-list permission in Spatie.

Please guide me if i am thinking wrong.

Comment: Answer for the second part of your question is listed below, And for the first part as you said it generates error, Please paste the error in description as well.

Comment: it just showing me it does't have specific permission if i assign role-list permission then it works smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am telling answer to my own question, in constructor if i have first method without any permission assign to method below.

```
 $this->middleware('permission:role-list');
```

so if any role doesn't have this permission it generate an error the role doesn't have permission for this and it does not check next permission.

Answer (score 0):

*To restrict the middleware to only certain methods on the controller class we use **only**.*

```
$this->middleware('permission:role-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
```

Now the above lines only applies the listed middleware on **create** and **store** method.